# Listar o nome de todos objetos dentro do array

Tags: javascript, html, array, angularjs

Eu to usando o sistema de chips do Angular JS e to com um problema na hora de mostrar o nome(descrição) dos objetos que estão dentro do array.
O código `html` é esse:

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
                <div flex>
                    <div class="label-view">Esportes</div>
                    <md-chip>{{ ctrl.esportes[0].nome}}</md-chip>
                </div>
</div>
```

E o código que tá no `js` é esse:

```
this.esportes = [{id: 5, descricao: "Futebol"}, {id: 6, descricao: "Basquete"}]
```

No `html` só esta mostrando o primeiro por causa do `esportes[0]` mas eu quero que mostre todos que tem dentro do array `esportes` independente do tamanho dele.
Caso tenha ficado confuso, eu deixei o código nesse site: [codePen](https://codepen.io/guickz/pen/jOWXBEe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso vc precisa de um repeat para percorrer todos os objetos.

repare no insert que eu fiz: `<md-chips input-aria-label="Esportes favoritos" ng-repeat="chipText in ctrl.chipText">`

O `ng-repeat="chipText in ctrl.chipText"` irá percorrer todo o `ctrl.chipText`.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
      .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  function DemoCtrl ($timeout, $q) {
    this.chipText = [{id: 5, descricao: "Futebol"}, {id: 6, descricao: "Basquete"}]
  }
})();
```

```html
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content class="md-padding" layout="column">
    <h2>Static chips.</h2>

    <md-chips input-aria-label="Esportes favoritos" ng-repeat="chipText in ctrl.chipText">
      <md-chip>
               {{chipText.descricao}}
      </md-chip>
    </md-chips>

  </md-content>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.0/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.24/angular-material.js"></script>
```

Veja Funcionando [Aqui](https://codepen.io/rebecanonato/pen/VweqpzW)

Comment: só não é muito legal é colocar o mesmo nome `chipText` na interação ...